# How to get every iteration of a group in a regex as a separate group?

Tags: c++, regex, qregularexpression

I have a tough time figuring out a regular expression (something I have sadly almost not experience with) for the following problem:

- text starting with a given prefix (let's say it's `ab4`)
- text has a body of 4 blocks of 4 characters (that's what the `4` in `ab4` stands for) each of which can be an ASCII alpha-numeric, whitespace, brackets, hyphen or a dot (basically `a-zA-Z0-9 ()-.`). Example: `abcd`, `.b a`, , `b(a.)` are all valid single blocks.
- text body can be empty (`ab4` is the only content) or contain up to the four blocks (`ab4xxxx`, `ab4xxxxxxxx`, `ab4xxxxxxxxxxxx`, `ab4xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx` with `x` being a valid character)
- text end with a CR (carriage return - `\r\n`). The ending is counted as a terminating character and is NOT part of the body

So far I have come up with

```
.*ab4([a-zA-Z0-9 ()-.]{4}){1,4}\\r\\n.*
```

I use [regular expressions 101](https://regex101.com) to verify my regex before I add it to my C++ code. However if I input

```
ab4aaa bbb ccc ddd \r\n
```

I get the following stats:

- **Full match:**

  `0-25 'ab4aaa bbb ccc ddd \r\n'`
- **Group 1.:**

  `15-19 'ddd '`

The regex verifier tells me that

> A repeated capturing group will only capture the last iteration. Put a
>   capturing group around the repeated group to capture all iterations or
>   use a non-capturing group instead if you're not interested in the data

but frankly I have no idea what this means. I tried `(([a-zA-Z0-9 ()-.]{4}){1,4})` which didn't change much.

I'm looking for a better grouping namely one that **sets the 4 blocks apart** as separate groups. For the example above I'm expecting

- **Full match:**

  `0-25 'ab4aaa bbb ccc ddd \r\n'`

  - **Group 1.:**

  `0-3 'aaa '`

  - **Group 1.:**

  `4-7 'bbb '`

  - **Group 3.:**

  `8-11 'ccc '`

  - **Group 4.:**

  `12-15 'ddd '`

Comment: What is the regex library you are using? `std::regex`? Just to clarify: in *every* regex, there are as many *groups* in the resulting match object as there are *capturing groups* inside the pattern. That number is *constant*. What you might use is the *capture* collection. However, there are only 3 regex engines supporting that feature.

Comment: I'm using the `QRegularExpression` class that is shipped with Qt. So far I know for sure it supports groups, which can be returned through the `QList<QString> QRegularExpression::capturedTexts()` function with the first capture always being the full match and the subsequent captures being the single groups.

Comment: Ok, that means you are using PCRE that does not support a capture stack for each group, so you will have to use a 2-step approach: 1) extract whole matches capturing the part you will need to process further, and 2) a smaller regex that will match multiple occurrences of the necessary pattern inside the captured data in each match. The first one will be `ab4((?:[a-zA-Z0-9 ().-]{4}){1,4})\\r\\n` (note the hyphen is at the end) and the second is `[a-zA-Z0-9 ().-]{4}` or even `.{4}` or check if there  are other ways to split a string into substrings of 4-char strings in Qt.

Comment: So basically I can iterate through the whole string, apply my regex and if one is found (at the end) I chop it off and then repeat until there are no more matches left?

Comment: You iterate to find all matches, and each time the match is found, grab `captured(1)` and [split it into substrings of length 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16709314/split-string-using-loop-to-specific-length-sub-units).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using PCRE regex engine (with `QRegularExpression`) that does not support a capture stack for each group, so you will have to use a 2-step approach:

- Extract whole matches capturing the part you will need to process further, and
- Split each capture into 4-char parts.

The first extracting regex will be

```
ab4((?:[a-zA-Z0-9 ().-]{4}){1,4})\\r\\n
   ^                 ^          ^
```

Note I added capturing parentheses round the part you are interested in, and the hyphen is at the end of the character class.

Use the pattern to [extract all matches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22493129/3832970) from the text.

Then split the `match.captured(1)` into [substrings of length 4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16709499/3832970). You do not really need to use a regex for this step since the string is already pre-validated during the first regex step.

Comment: It works. The only think I feel the need to point out is that you can use `QStringRef` for getting the smaller 4-character-long chunks instead of using `std::substr`. It just creates a more readable code since you don't need to convert to `std::string` back and forth. I also added a `?` after the last parenthesis and before the `\\r` since otherwise the case `ab4\r\n` will not be covered.

Comment: Good. Also, you may just use `\\R` to match any line break sequence.

Comment: Hmmm, actually it doesn't work. -_- Try putting 8 or 16 (perhaps higher numbers are also possible) instead of the 4 inside the `{4}` and test it on the `ab4aaa bbb ccc  ddd\r\n` string. It works everytime. In order to make sure it's not my extra `?` I removed it but the problem still exists.

Comment: Btw the `\\R` is not necessary since the strings ALWAYS end with a CR.

Comment: The `ab4aaa bbb ccc ddd` with a space at the end? [`{8,16}` does not match that string](https://regex101.com/r/VVIcSc/1)

Comment: There is no space at the end (unless the last block contains one). I mean if you change [`ab4((?:[a-zA-Z0-9 ().-]{4}){1,4})\\r\\n`](https://regex101.com/r/KvqW1B/4) to [`ab4((?:[a-zA-Z0-9 ().-]{8}){1,4})\\r\\n`](https://regex101.com/r/mLg5OL/1). The number of blocks isn't changed.

Comment: So, you mean the whitespace is not to be counted in as a field char? I am sorry, but that part of your question is not really covered in the post, i.e. the pattern requirements are not provided. Just now, I can suggest [`ab4([a-zA-Z0-9().-]{3}(?:\s+[a-zA-Z0-9().-]{3}){0,3})?\s*\\r\\n`](https://regex101.com/r/mLg5OL/2), but I am not really sure it will work in all scenarios (why `.` and `-` are there? Can they be used like whitespace?) You should redefine what block is in your question.

Comment: Whitespace is counted as a field char. The `.` and `-` are there since each block may contain those. I'm just wondering why I get the same result for the whole string no matter if I select the length of a single block to be 4, 8 or 16.

Comment: @rbaleksandar It is easy to explain - compare [{4}](https://regex101.com/r/9BLx9Y/1) version against the `[{8}`](https://regex101.com/r/9BLx9Y/2) version. See the red highlight? It still matches the string, just the single block length is different.

Comment: *facepalm* Indeed. Also because of the `{1,4}` condition if we have 8 characters for a block size of 4 there will be 2 blocks but for a size of 8 there will be only 1.